# C# - Extract one *.jar file into another one

Tags: c#, jar, extract

I am trying to do my own Minecraft Launcher for Moded Minecraft. And I have a issue: I need to extract content of one *.jar file to another. I tried a lot of things and I am totally desperate.

Basicly, I need to do [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35123963/Untitled.mp4) in code.

Comment: A jar file is a zip archive with a different extension. Your question is quite vague, but I'm guessing you want the contents of the jar file. Have you tried using any zip libraries, external or part of the .NET framework?

Comment: You mention that you've tried a lot of things. Can you give details?

Comment: Depending on degree of file manipulation you need to perform there can be easier way than in-code. If you just need to repack archives it can be easier to simply put [unzip.exe](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html) next to main executable and just call it. If you want to do it in code then in .NET 4.5 (or maybe from 4.0?) support for zip's is good enough to do it without additional libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1937294/andrew) briefly mentioned, there are some good .NET libraries for manipulating zip files. I've found [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to be very useful, and there are lots of helpful worked examples [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

In answer to your question, if you just want to copy the contents of one *.jar file to another, keeping original content in the target file, please try the following. I'm using the .NET zip mentioned above (which also has a NuGet package!):

```
using (ZipFile sourceZipFile = ZipFile.Read("zip1.jar"))
        using (ZipFile targetZipFile = ZipFile.Read("zip2.jar"))
        {
            foreach (var zipItem in sourceZipFile)
            {
                if (!targetZipFile.ContainsEntry(zipItem.FileName))
                {
                    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        // Write the contents of this zip item to a stream
                        zipItem.Extract(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;

                        // Now use the contents of this stream to write to the target file
                        targetZipFile.AddEntry(zipItem.FileName, stream);

                        // Save the target file. We need to do this each time before we close
                        // the stream
                        targetZipFile.Save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps!